# Adding element's comments to sample result save configuration

Tags: jmeter

I have a HTTP Request sample and want to know how to save "Comments" field content when I choose `write results to file` in `View Results Tree`.
Is it possible to add a option to `Sample Result Save Configuration`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of JMeter version 2.7 it is not possible and I doubt it will be implemented as it seems rather weird to do so.

Another option for you would be to add a Jmeter variable with a Beanshell Sampler :

- ${__BeanShell(vars.put("name"\,"value"))}

and configure saveservice so that it saves it using sample_variables field:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html